# How to link to a specific comment on Amazon

Tags: amazon

Some Amazon articles have hundreds of comments.

How can I create a link to a specific one for sharing?

Answer (score 2):

It is a little tricky. Click on the customer's name that left the review, then click to view their reviews on the left side. When you have found and clicked on their review, you will get a "Permalink" hyperlink, click on that and you will get a web address for the review.